# Overstay in Spain on my tourist visa

Tags: visas, spain, overstaying, visa-extensions

I have over stay my nationality is Nigeria I came on December 23 December 2018 and my visa expired on December 29 2018 but my and on 27 of December were given appointment on January 4 and on 4th she was admitted she gave birth and our visa has expired since on 29th December can d visa still be extended and what are d procedure to take because my babby can't travelled nao and I husband I want to go back and I don't want the country to say I have over stay can my visa extended can be done and where and were to go pls I am wumi

Comment: Is your wife Spanish or an EU citizen? Are you looking to try to live in Spain or just get an extension until you can go home? What is your nationality? Please edit this information into the question.

Comment: Was your wife unable to travel?

Comment: I have over stay my nationality is Nigeria I came on December 23 December 2018 and my visa expired on December 29 2018 but my and on 27 of December were given appointment on January 4 and on 4th she was admitted she gave birth and our visa has expired since on 29th December can d visa still be extended and what are d procedure to take because my babby can't travelled nao and I husband I want to go back and I don't want the country to say I have over stay can my visa extended can be done and where and were to go pls I am wumi

Comment: I have over stay my nationality is Nigeria I came on December 23 December 2018 and my visa expired on December 29 2018 but my and on 27 of December were given appointment on January 4 and on 4th she was admitted she gave birth and our visa has expired since on 29th December can d visa still be extended and what are d procedure to take because my babby can't travelled nao and I husband I want to go back and I don't want the country to say I have over stay can my visa extended can be done and where and were to go pls I am wumi